# E.O. Wilson on sociobiology and the origin of morality

Tags: ethology, sociality, sociobiology, eusociality

Somewhere in E.O Wilson's writing, he discusses how human values are rooted in our nature as a specific kind of animal. He argues that we have an identifiable optimal living place -- a grove at the top of a hill, with surrounding grassland give an area of clear view, overlooking a body of water. He then goes on to further make this case by imagining that naked mole rats have risen to intelligence. He pens a speech that such a being might give on some patriotic holiday. And boy howdy, it sure does not sound like any epideictic speech you could imagine a human giving. The use of shit as a metaphor for sustenance alone is sufficiently jarring, but there were a bunch more, all firmly anchored in aspects of mole rat biology and social structure that differ from ours.

I would like to cite and quote this passage. I thought this was either in Biophilia or Consilience, but I have not been able to find it in either book, or in a bunch of other searches via google scholar, and through my own books and ebooks of his.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? Can you point me toward where I would find it?

Comment: @com.prehensible If andrewH could quote the section verbatim, I'm sure it would be easy for him to find the relevant text. 

To andrewH: I have not actually read any of EO Wilson's work, although I'm familiar with it from secondary sources. Have you looked in 'Sociobiology: The New Synthesis' or 'On Human Nature'?

Comment: It could also be from 'The Biophilia Hypothesis.' But I don't know at all for sure.

Comment: If human values are rooted in our nature, why don't we all have the same values?

Comment: @Eff it would be good to state the source of the information and the logic of the metaphor, not confuse readers with garden-fence English: we can't hear the vocal tone of the theatrically phrased question, without confusion. Indian, Australian and 2nd language english people don't understand Boy Howdy and epideictic! most of us have to fetch a dictionary. E O Wilson doesn't start his written phrases with And! E O Wilson is kind and if you address him a written request, he will respond to you in writing through is secretary or by mail / email. My friend wrote to him and had a signed letter.

Comment: @com.prehensible That's fair. And I think it's a good idea to email EO Wilson.

Comment: 1930's professors are happy with handwritten mail, they may be diligent with email, it's hit and miss.

Comment: I think its from "Genesis, the deep origin of societies"

Comment: @jamesqf Humans are a complicated mix of instinct and reflection.  Wilson isn't trying to claim that everything you think and believe is rooted solely in your evolutionary history.  What he states in this arena is actually rather non-controversial, that human values are founded on evolutionary contingencies that would differ if we had emerged via a different natural history.  Let's take, for example, a taboo against killing small children.  You could claim that certain societies do kill small children but they always have to justify the act, implying that this is something that naturally makes

Comment: @jamesqf Humans uncomfortable.  This would not necessarily be the case in a society of intelligent pelicans, who always lay more eggs than they support and kill at least one child from almost every litter.  Such a society might consider it natural to have a minimum age to be worthy of moral consideration, whereas we would find such a thing abhorrent.  While our beliefs and social structures are heavily culturally influenced, even those cultural influences are ultimately contingent on our biology.

Comment: @Jeremiah: "...whereas we would find such a thing abhorrent." But not all humans do, or have historically.  E.g. the classical practice of exposing unwanted infants, or Victorian foundling homes.  And at the other extreme, we have the "pro-life" types who want to push that minimum age to before birth, even to conception, and others who find that abhorrent.

Comment: @jamesqf the thing about that is that we are aware of these practice because of justifications put in writing by the cultures that did these things because they were aware of the need for justification. This is something that is a moral hazard for us at all points in history. Things that have no moral dimension need no justification. What we even decide to pay attention to in the first place is driven by evolutionary contingencies. Human birth rates and reproductive strategies prime us to raise the killing of offspring as a moral issue in the first place.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Granted, I'm not an expert in the writings of ancient cultures (or even of Victorian England), but I don't know of them because of attempts to justify them, but simply because they were mentioned in passing as ordinary aspects of the culture.  I could also, given room enough and time, cite many more examples of things considered moral by one group, highly immoral by another.  For a current example, consider marijuana use in the US today.

Comment: @jamesfq but it wasn’t just a normal and accepted part of these societies. In Ancient Greece and Rome the practice of infanticide was seen as evil and barbarous, which is why they did it through exposure, to allay their own guilt by “putting it in the hands of the gods”. The same reason was behind infanticide by exposure in the Christian Middle Ages. In Victorian England infanticide was an unfortunate consequence of support being torn away from poor women, forcing them to do what they had to to survive but women were put on trial for this and could only escape litigation by claiming insanity.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Nope, not in _Genesis_.